# Issue installing USB_CAM on Groovy Raspbian

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, camera, usb-cam, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good night partners

I would like to use an usb camera (common usb camera) on my raspberry pi running groovy-raspbian.

I've just followed the instructions in

> http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi#ROS_Peripherals

At step 4.1  when I finally type **roscd usb_cam** I have the following:

> roscd: No such package/stack 'usb_cam

Where am I wrong? Where is my mistake?

Thanks you so much

EDIT1 : I have also downloaded this https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg-release/usb_cam-release/releases/tag/release%2Fgroovy%2Fusb_cam%2F0.1.3-0  but I'm not sure if it will help me. I don't really know how to proceed with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117856/issue-installing-usb_cam-on-groovy-raspbian/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that usb_cam is in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH so that the package can be found.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-01-16**:
Could you take a look on my answer below please?